# WebSql Questions about obtaining results from SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, methods, web, group-by, sum

I am developing an internet based software to manage a golf league, and was wondering how I would get a certain set of results. The code posted is BROKEN.

What I would like to happen:

Scores saved to table by team number
Scores are added together by team number
HTML elements are created displaying team number, and total points

Here is what I have:

```
function CalculateScoresPage(){
    var db=openDatabase('RecordOfScores','1.0','Record of net scores', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

    db.transaction(function(tx) {

        tx.executeSql('SELECT SUM(points) FROM LeaguesMadeEasyTeams GROUP BY teamNumber', [], function(tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length;
            var i;
            console.log(results);
            for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                $("#teams").append("<div class=\"teamEntry\">Team: "
                                   + results + " " + results.rows.item(i).points 
                                   + "</div>");
                console.log(results);
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: the +results+ and +results.rows.item(i).points+ is really just a placeholder. In all honesty, I do not know what to put here in THIS situation. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used WebSQL before, but in normal SQL, you can give your column a "regular" name like so: `select sum(points) points from...`. Then you should be able to refer to the column just as "points".

Answer (score 0):

You just missed the column's alias. You should try this:

```
function CalculateScoresPage(){
var db=openDatabase('RecordOfScores','1.0','Record of net scores', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function(tx) {

    tx.executeSql('SELECT SUM(points) as points FROM LeaguesMadeEasyTeams GROUP BY teamNumber', [], function(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        var i;
        console.log(results);
        for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            $("#teams").append("<div class=\"teamEntry\">Team: "
                               + results + " " + results.rows.item(i).points 
                               + "</div>");
            console.log(results);
        };
    });
});
```

}